# Embed YouTube IFrame responsive

Tags: html, responsive-design, youtube

I embedded YouTube video with the following link on a Magento site (Magento is not really important unless there is a plugin that I am not aware of)

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Zq-805aUM7M?feature=player_embedded" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I don't believe this piece of code is good because it is not responsive. 
How can I fix?

Comment: Just a suggest : http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed
You just need the Responsive embed css.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this pure `css` way:

```
iframe, object, embed {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
}
```

if that does not work try this

https://benmarshall.me/responsive-iframes/

Comment: I will try, please note that I still want it to start at the size of width="640" height="360" by default

Comment: (note) If it is used in Wordpress post, you can use `.entry-content iframe, .entry-content object, .entry-content embed` to replace only these tag in single post.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the best way to do it

```css
.youtube-video {
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
}
```

```html
<iframe class="youtube-video" src="<YOUR_YOUTUBE_VIDEO_URL>" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Also check [here](https://caniuse.com/?search=aspect-ratio) for browser compatibility of `aspect-ratio`

Comment: This seems like the cleanest solution to me. Doesn't require weird hacks with position absolute

Answer (score 2):

To specifically *target youtube videos*, and not all iframes or objects of embeds, you can use attribute selector based on string present in `src`.

```
iframe[src*=youtube]
{
  max-width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

This works for me, but anyway, [here you can find more solutions](https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php) for additional (specific) cases

Answer (score 1):

There is plenty of hints on the Web with suggestions to remove 'width' and 'height' attributes, which is impossible in some cases. But user may override these attributes with CSS

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; }
```

And the iframe:

```
.wrapper iframe[width][height] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important; }
```

Notice the [width] and [height] in the CSS selector and "!important" instructions - these are essential to override iframe's width and height attribute's values.

Answer (score 0):

I tried but non were truly responsive. So the used the following iframe & CSS

```
HTML:

    <iframe class="video-container"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-H2mmm5pMmY" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>


CSS:
.video-container {
position:relative;
height:22em;
width:-webkit-fill-available;
overflow:hidden;
}

.video-container iframe, .video-container object, .video-container embed {
position:relative;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this, which turns all iframe elements into 16:9:

```
<style>
.youtube-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
.youtube-container iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
}
</style>

<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oTLZci5dp44"></iframe>

<script>
$('iframe[src*="youtube"]').wrap('<div class="youtube-container"></div>');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this for my future website. Here's my script; I wonder what you think. It should work with any providers (youtube, vimeo, etc), preserves the original aspect ratio, and will work with any appended objects as long as you run videoIframe_MakeResponsive('youtube', '16/9') after updating the page. '16/9' is a default aspect ratio if width/height aren't specified. I hope this helps!

```js
// Greatest Common Divisor
function Math_gcd(a, b) {
    if (a<b)
        [a, b] = [b, a]
    return b ? Math_gcd(b, a%b) : a
}

// get ratio ('16/9' or something) from dimensions
function Math_ratio(width, height) {
    const gcd = Math_gcd(width, height)
    return width/gcd + '/' + height/gcd
}

// add multiple css properties
function css(element, jsonCSS) {
    for (const property in jsonCSS)
        element.style[property] = jsonCSS[property]
}

// autorun
function autorun(callback) {
    if (document.readyState != 'loading')
        callback()
    else
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', callback)
}

// responsive iframe
function videoIframe_MakeResponsive(provider, defaultRatio = '16/9') {
    document.querySelectorAll('iframe[src*="' + provider + '"]').forEach(iframe => {
        if (!iframe.classList.contains('videoIframeFixed')) { // fix only new iframes
            let width = iframe.getAttribute('width')
            let height = iframe.getAttribute('height')
            let aspectratio = (width && height) ? Math_ratio(width, height) : defaultRatio
            iframe.removeAttribute('width') // reset
            iframe.removeAttribute('height') // reset
            iframe.classList.add('videoIframeFixed') // for future reference
            // wrapper container
            let wrapper = document.createElement('div')
            iframe.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, iframe)
            wrapper.appendChild(iframe) // move iframe inside
            // style
            css(wrapper, {
                'width': '100%',
                'position': 'relative',
                'aspect-ratio': aspectratio
            })
            css(iframe, {
                'width': '100%',
                'height': '100%',
                'position': 'absolute'
            })
        }
    })
}

// run it on page load
autorun(function () {
    videoIframe_MakeResponsive('youtube')
    videoIframe_MakeResponsive('vimeo')
    /* ... etc ... */
})
```

Answer (score -1):

First, set the width and height for the iframe to match your proportions - for me it's 16by9:

```
<figure>
    <iframe class="youtube-video" width="640" height="360" src="..." allowfullscreen></iframe>
</figure>
<script>
    $(function(){
        var
            $allVideos = $("iframe[src*='//player.vimeo.com'], iframe[src*='//www.youtube.com'], object, embed")
            ,$fluidEl = $("figure")
        ;
        $allVideos.each(function() {
            $(this).attr('data-aspectRatio', this.height / this.width).removeAttr('height').removeAttr('width');
        });
        $(window).resize(function(){
            var newWidth = $fluidEl.width();
            $allVideos.each(function(){
                var $el = $(this);
                $el.width(newWidth).height(newWidth * $el.attr('data-aspectRatio'));
            });
        }).resize();
    });
</script>
```

[Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/embed/) owners (possibly lower) are more fortunate:

```
<figure class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="youtube-video" width="640" height="360" src="..." allowfullscreen></iframe>
</figure>
```